# In iOS App, how to scroll two UIView simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, scroll, uiwebview

I am developing iOS App.

I add UITextView(100px height) on top of UIWebView and would like to make them scroll simultaneously.

I am writing down the following code. However, when I scroll my screen, only UIWebView is scrolled and UITextView isn't.(UITextView is fixed!)

I hope that when I scroll up my screen, both UIWebView and UITextView go up, and vice versa.

Could you tell me how to solve?

```
@interface DetailViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>{
     UITextView *recommendText;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *detailPage;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self headerMake];
}

-(void)headerMake{

    recommendText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,100)];
    recommendText.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    recommendText.text = @"hogehoge";
    [self.detailPage addSubview:recommendText];

    [[self.detailPage scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A text view is a scroll view subclass, and web views have a `scrollView` property.
Listen to both scroll views content offset change (using `scrollViewDidScroll:`) and update the content offset of the other scroll view accordingly. This will give you the effect of scrolling the two at the same time.

```
self.textview.delegate = self;
self.webview.scrollView.delegate = self;

...

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == self.textview)
    {
        self.webview.scrollView.contentOffset = self.textview.contentOffset;
    }
    else
    {
        self.textview.contentOffset = self.webview.scrollView.contentOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. If possible, could you tell me sample code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did above code. Certainly, when scroll up, the text of textview goes up in textview, however i would like to go up textview itself. Any solution?

Comment: I think your question is misleading then. You should add the text view as a subview of the UIWebView scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you should embed them both is a scroll view and disable scrolling in the UIWebview and the UITextView. then they will scroll as one. Although you may have to dynamically set the sizes of the Textview and webview if they have different content they have to support.